# Connecting Oracle and ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, oracle-spatial

How can I Connect between Oracle 64 bit 11g and Arcgis 10.1?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions for [**Setting up a connection to Oracle**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002n00000038000000)?  Are you using the ArcSDE component of ArcGIS for Server?

Comment: yes , I read it 

but I dont understand it clearly?

Comment: I think it will be best if you list the steps that seem to work as described in order to highlight where the instructions lose you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to ArcCatalog -> Database Connections -> Add Database Connections -> Database Platform: Oracle.

This is setting up in arcmap:

[image]